# angular.isUndefined() function working abruptly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
    .filter("unique", function () {
        return function (data, propertyName) {
            if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
                var results = [];
                var keys = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var val = data[i][propertyName];
                    console.log(angular.isUndefined(keys[val]))
                    if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                        keys[val] = true;
                        results.push(val);
                    }
                }
                return results;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
```

i am new to angularjs and facing problem with [angular.isUndefined()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined) function.

So the issue is like i am adding properties to an object with the help of `for` loop and also checking that if a particular property is already defined for the object, if the property is defined then i am not adding that property to the object but when i am using `angular.isUndefined()` to check the property it returns `false` even when the property is there in the object and keeps doing so two times and for the third time it returns true when i call `angular.isUndefined()`.

Please help in here.

Comment: Could you provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Your description of the issue is confusing because you say "...when i am using `angular.isUndefined()` to check the property it returns `false` even when the property is there..." angular.isUndefined() *should* return false when the property exists. Also remember that undefined !== null.